# ¿Un AsyncTask me sirve para verificar conexión con un WebService?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Estaba leyendo en la página de AsyncTask de Android Developers ([AsyncTask | Android Developers)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) y recomiendan paquetes de `java.util.concurrent`  tales como Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor y FutureTask. Sin embargo, lo que yo quiero hacer es ejecutar un hilo cada cierto tiempo para que haga peticiones al servidor del WebService y saber si hay conexión al mismo o no. Ya tengo lo que me dirá si habrá conexión o no, pero no sé como hacer peticiones periódicas al WS, por eso terminé investigando sobre AsyncTask.

¿Podrían guiarme un poco? Entiendo que no es una pregunta concreta, pero según las reglas solo no es recomendable hacer este tipo de preguntas, no está prohibido. Seguro que nos sirve a muchos.

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres decir con *«verificar conexión con un WebService»*. ¿Lo que quieres es usar `AsyncTask` para verificar si el WS está funcionando, o si el cliente tiene conexión activa a internet (digo esto porque por ejemplo en Wifi puede haber conexión, pero no transmisión de datos, en caso de que el router no tenga ADSL por ejemplo), o si el cliente tiene conexión pero el WS no funciona (servidor caído u otro)... Y otra pregunta, ¿por qué no usas Volley?

Comment: Lo de Internet ya lo tengo solucionado, me interesa saber si el WS está "activo", recibiendo peticiones y mandando respuesta, tengo cubierto si la petición se lleva a cabo o falla. Pero no sé como hacer esta verificación constantemente para hacer los procedimientos de Log y otras peticiones (no registro) localmente con una base de datos SQLite.

Comment: No conozco Volley, gracias por mencionarlo (lo guardaré por ahí), pero no tengo tiempo para aprender a usarlo y entenderlo.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a qué se debe tu requerimiento. Generalmente, lo que indica que el WS está activo es que le mandas algo o le pides algo y recibes o no recibes una respuesta de parte del WS o una respuesta con un código de error o algo así. No sé tampoco si el WS es responsabilidad tuya o es de terceros. Sea como sea, si en tu contexto se requiere una especie de petición simple en la que consultas al WS y éste te responde (una especie de `ping`) lo podrías programar. Algo dirigido a una URL como `example.com/status` que devuelve `true` o `false` según el estado del WS...

Comment: ... lo que pasa es que ni siquiera queda claro qué quieres decir con que *«el WS esté activo»*. Son cosas que dependen de muchos contextos.. ¿qué es activo, que está operacional? o ¿qué está dentro de una franja horaria donde se pueden agregar datos por ejemplo? En cuanto a `Volley` no es demasiado complicado aprenderlo, es una librería muy sencilla y, al menos en mi caso, me sirve también para saber si hay conexión o no en el cliente o si el servidor respondió con un status `200` o un estatus `404` o con `500` o con cualquier tipo de error, porque tiene un método propio para manejo de errores